# Most efficient way to sum up an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to find a sub-`O(n)` method to calculate the sum of an integer array ~~~(instead of iterating through `0 - n`, I am doing it in `n/2`)~~~ **I'm still doing it in O(n)**.

```
public static int sum(int[] s) {
    int length = s.length - 1;
    int half = length/2;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= half; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + s[i] + " + " + s[length - i]);
        sum += s[i] + s[length - i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

My algorithm works for even number of integers, however, when there are odd number of integers, it would sum the middle index twice:

Test:

```
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    System.out.println(sum(arr));
```

Output:

```
0 1 + 5
1 2 + 4
2 3 + 3
Sum: 18
```

My question is - what is the best way to sum up the middle index for odd-number of numbers?

Comment: This is still `O(n)`, just so you know. You have the same number of additions. You only avoided incrementing `i` `n` times, but now you're doing a subtraction.

Comment: `O(n)` is equal to `O(n/2)`.

Comment: If your array values follows a trend for example the index, it can be less than O(n), else, the lowest will be O(n).

Comment: Real life efficiency is not that closely related to big O's. The constant factor matters. So what do you want here, theoretical time complexity (can't do any better than O(n), obviously) or real life efficiency?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys - this way when correctly implemented actually is slower than iterating through each index. I feel stupid now =)

Comment: You will have an issue if the array consist from one element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's still O(n) even if you go from 0 to n/2 at the end of the day you are touching every element of the array at least one time. And to sum up an array of integers the least you can do is O(n) because you have to touch every element in the array one time to include it in the sum.

Comment: Crap. I didn't know that.. Woops. So there's no benefit to doing it this way vs iterating through each element and summing them?

Comment: No not at all actually your are complicating it on yourself :)

Comment: Haha.. I was adapting the string-reversal technique (where you swap the `i` and `length - i` index) onto this problem. I guess I'm really overthinking it.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage No. In fact, a correct implementation of your method would be slower than simply iterating through all indexes and summing the elements.

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto I agree, since I'll need a conditional to determine if it's odd/even

Comment: Yes but still even the string swaping technique is O(n). When you try to get the order of your algorithm always try to think how many time you access each element in your array. Also @FernandoMatsumoto is right not only because the odd/even thing also because of memory caching when you access an array in order you make use of the cache while the way of accessing it the way you did is more likely to cause page miss.

Answer (score 0):

You solution is O(n), not sub-O(n). Just by adding two numbers inside the loop does not change it. There is no way to make it sub-O(n), as you need to iterate over all numbers.