# How to find all sums in an int array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops

I have an array of integers, example
{2,3,7}
and I need to find how to find a number as a sum of these numbers

For example, let's say I need to find **17**

I could do 7+2+2+3+3, 7+2+2+2+2+2, 7+3+7, 3+3+3+2+2+2+2, etc.

But looping through everything is very inefficient, it would be O(N^N) in the best case...

How would i solve a problem like this in an optimized way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673076/most-efficient-way-to-sum-up-an-array-of-integers/32673107

Comment: This is the Coin-change problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849795/is-there-a-more-optimal-solution-to-this-money-change-problem/64853504#64853504

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking StackOverflow to help you solve the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). If you manage to find a polynomial solution, you can go claim a [million dollars reward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems) for solving P=NP. Good luck !

Comment: The solution though non-polynomial still exists using DP.

Comment: @SerialLazer indeed there is, and a greedy algorithm would even find the solution in a polynomial time assuming the  set contains the right values (like {2,3,7}) ; but the general case of the OP's problem will still not be solved on a coding forum. The dynamic algorithm's pseudo polynomial complexity merely hides the NP-hardness in a fixed parameter. As far as I know, it does not make it magically polynomial to solve

Comment: I don't think he is looking for a polynomial run time.